# How to relocate my solution (.sln) file to a different location

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, solution

I need to relocate my solution file to the root folder, I tried to do it in Visual studio from File-> Save .sln As, but it doesn't let me to change the location. Appreciate any advise for this.

Comment: We need a bit more information I believe - what is the path of the solution currently, and what is the path you are trying to save it to?

Comment: my solution file So.DS.API.sln is located in C:\Projects\System\SoDSAPI\So.DS.API. I'd like to take it one level up and relocate it to C:\Projects\System\SoDSAPI

Answer (score 0):

Just move it there by hand (using the explorer). Make sure you have closed Visual Studio first. Then open the solution file in a text editor and change the relative path of the project(s) within it. You will see a section of the form

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "SoDSAPI", "So.DS.API.csproj", "{94DBA414-3A51-47AB-A91E-92475B86AF9A}"
EndProject
```

The second parameter (`"So.DS.API.csproj"`) is the relative path from the solution to the project. It probably doesn't include a folder for you, since you had the solution and the project in the same folder before. Change that to include the project folder, so the value changes to `"So.DS.API\So.DS.API.csproj"`. Save the file and then start VS again.